# Code turns dark blue after trying to run it

Tags: programming

I have a large amount of data in my N-Body Code. I imagine *Mathematica* doesn't really like this, but is there any other reason for my code turning a navy blue colour after I try to run it?

Comment: What do you mean by "try to run"?  What does Mathematica actually do: return unevaluated, run seemingly forever, etc?  Also, can you provide a reduced example that exhibits the same behavior?

Comment: I think you run out of RAM, then the MMA kernels shut down. If from evaluation menu you quit the kernels you get the same blue code.

Comment: I have never seen all the symbols in a notebook's input cells turn blue, indicating they have become undefined, after an evaluation. I have seen user-defined symbols turn blue after a kernel crash, but built-in symbols have always remained black. Please clarify the extent to which you are getting blue symbols.

Comment: @m_goldberg: When the kernel is quit, all symbols and built-in commands (except numbers and punctuation) turns dark blue. It's one of the default syntax colorings. If you don't have good color vision, you may mistake the dark blue for black, which could explain why you haven't observed it (it's a pretty dark blue, but it's not black).

Comment: So as yashar pointed out, it sounds like your kernel is dying when you run it.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus. I do have impaired vision, and, as you say, that may explain my being unaware of this dark blue coloring .

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Would you please post that as an answer?